# Restore windows server image backup from one server to another

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

Can I restore and Windows Server 2008 built in image backup from one server to a different hardware? Is that possible?

I have a PowerEdge T710 and I want to restore to T300.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, up to a point. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249694) article tells you how. Note particularly the need to install drivers for the target system, and under Troubleshooting, how to tell the system to re-detect the HAL.

Also useful, a simpler guide to bare-metal restore on Windows 2008 server [here](http://www.wbadmin.info/articles/howto-bare-metal-restores-windows-server-2008-backup.html).

Good luck!