# Easy to restore Windows 2008 backup to another server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-backup

I am using the native Windows 2008 backup to do nightly backups. It is using an entire drive as the backup. Can I restore the files on a different machine completely, or does it have to be on the same machine? Does it work the same way in Windows 7 / W2K8 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question is answered already: [Restore windows server image backup from one server to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/139724/restore-windows-server-image-backup-from-one-server-to-another)

Second question: While the feature set in R2 provides more options (best one is using UNC network path as backup location) the core VSS-based (image) backups feature is the same.  To restore to the *same* machine just boot to the install disk and choose repair to get started.  In summary Win7/2008R2 backups are same or better then Vista/2008.